# Iphone keyboard with numbers, decimal point and minus sign

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I am writing an iphone app that requires numeric input.  I am using textfield to receive user input, none of the built in keyboards provision for numbers, decimal point and minus sign.  Do I require a custom keyboard?

Comment: Undo and RMaddy, make up your mind!  (I think they're both correct -- you need to use a version of the standard decimal KB and overlay buttons for the others.  There are several versions of this hack out there if you search for them.)

Comment: @HotLicks We're enemies. We have to say the opposite of each other. Unfortunately, rmaddy is always right :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

What you can do is use the `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` keyboard type to get the numbers and decimal point.

Then you create a simple view that has buttons for + and - and perhaps Next/Prev and/or a Done button. This view is then used as the text field's `inputAccessoryView`. This view will appear just above the keyboard. You will need to handle the button events to update the value in the text field yourself.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

You just said that none of the built-in keyboards have a decimal point and minus sign. Therefore, you need a custom keyboard.

`UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` will get you half way there. It has (as the name suggests) a decimal character in the keyboard. No minus sign, though.